# Multiple WebService Implementors on single Endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have the following classes that implements an interface and publishes an endpoint.

**SayHelloImpl.java**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.suture.self.wsdl.SayHello")
@HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")
public class SayHelloImpl implements SayHello {
    ...
    ...
}
```

**EndpointPublisher.java**

```
public class EndpointPublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://sutureself.com/greeter", new SayHelloImpl());
    }
}
```

At present, it all works perfectly for SayHello, but now I want to add another web service, SayGoodbye (below)

**SayGoodbyeImpl.java**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.suture.self.wsdl.SayGoodbye")
@HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")
public class SayGoodbyeImpl implements SayGoodbye {
    ...
    ...
}
```

How do I now publish the endpoint with two (or more) implementors?  I have tried implementing both interfaces in the one class, which is fine, but the number of interfaces could grow, and this could get very cluttered quickly.  Ideally, I want to implement a single interface in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple WebMethod in a WebService.

```
@WebService
@HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")
public class WSImpl implements SayHello, SayGoodbye {
    ... // impl SayHello methods
    ... // impl SayGoodBye methods
}
```

and

```
Endpoint.publish("http://sutureself.com/greeter", new WSImpl());
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer.  Yeah I had tried this also (I'll update my question).  My only problem with this approach is that there could be any number of interfaces to implement, so it could get very messy very quickly.